# HIghcharts gauge unwanted white borders

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, gauge

I came up with a highchart gauge code that renders very nice on JSFiddle, but as I copy/paste it into my website, it seems like all the 'border' options (borderColor and borderWidth) do not respond, and the browser automatically put white borders on my series, on the tooltip and on the gauge's several backgroundradius, which I don't want, which not only gives a poor visual but also prevent the series from appearing clearly !

Here's the JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/roamdam/p67ebL0L/6/

```
var legend1 = "<span style='font-weight:100'>Un peu</span>",
    legend2 = "<span style='font-weight:100'>Beaucoup</span>",
    legend3 = "<span style='font-weight:100'>Pas du <br/>tout</span>";




$(function () {

    // Uncomment to style it like Apple Watch

    if (!Highcharts.theme) {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: 'none'
            },
            colors: ['#CBA148', '#0092B9', '#107671']
        });
    }
    // 

    Highcharts.chart('gauge', {

        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            marginTop: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: '',
        },

        tooltip: {
            borderWidth : 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'Gill Sans'
            },
            pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
            positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
                return {
                    x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                    y: 150
                };
            }
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            background: [{ // Track for 'un peu H'
                outerRadius: '112%',
                innerRadius: '100%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),            
                borderWidth:0,


            }, { // Track for 'un peu F'
                outerRadius: '100%',
                innerRadius: '88%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                 borderWidth:0,


            }, { // Track for Beaucoup H
                outerRadius: '87%',
                innerRadius: '75%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                                borderWidth:0,


            }, { // Track for Beaucoup F
                outerRadius: '75%',
                innerRadius: '63%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }, { // Track for Pas du tout H
                outerRadius: '62%',
                innerRadius: '50%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }, { // Track for Pas du tou F
                outerRadius: '50%',
                innerRadius: '38%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
                borderWidth: 0
            }]
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 60,
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickPositions: []
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                borderWidth: 17,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                linecap : 'round',
                stickyTracking: false
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: '(hommes) <br/><b>Un peu :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '106%',
                innerRadius: '106%',
                y: 40
            }]
        }, {
            name: '(femmes) <br/><b>Un peu :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                radius: '94%',
                innerRadius: '94%',
                y: 51
            }]
        } , {
            name: '(hommes) <br/><b>Beaucoup :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                radius: '81%',
                innerRadius: '81%',
                y: 49
            }]
        }, {
            name: '(femmes) <br/><b>Beaucoup :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
                radius: '69%',
                innerRadius: '69%',
                y: 36
            }]
        } , {
            name: '(hommes) <br/><b>Pas du tout :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                        data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                radius: '56%',
                innerRadius: '56%',
                y: 11
            }]
        }, {
            name: '(femmes) <br/><b>Pas du tout :</b>',
            borderColor:Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                        data: [{
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
                radius: '44%',
                innerRadius: '44%',
                y: 15
            }]
        }]
    },

    /**
     * In the chart load callback, add icons on top of the circular shapes
     */
    function callback() {

        // Move icon
        this.renderer.text(legend1, -55, 5)
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 26)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Exercise icon
        this.renderer.text(legend2, -65, 10)
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 61)
            .add(this.series[2].group);

        // Stand icon
        this.renderer.text(legend3,-50,5)
            .attr({
                'stroke': '#303030',
                'stroke-linecap': 'round',
                'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                'zIndex': 10
            })
            .translate(190, 96)
            .add(this.series[2].group);
    });


});
```

And attached is [a capture of what the code renders on my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4V5z.png) (browser : Safari but does the same on Firefox).
Could it be a browser problem ?

Comment: Maybe you have some CSS styles which cause that? Or maybe you have conflict with other libraries? Or maybe simply you use old version of Highcharts and gauge in your local app?

Comment: The problem indeed came from the `<style>` section in the `<head>` part of html document, which defined `path.stroke:white` and `path.stroke-width:1px`, but initially for only one graph. Deleting those parameters and adpating the other graph's options solved the problem. `path` is an option for svg isn't it ? That's why it interfered with my gauge script ? Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely on your site you have altered the plotOptions solidgauge, borderWidth field, this is probably not behaving how you think it would. Those nice colored, rounded lines, are not actually the series line, they are the border of the series line. The white lines you see on your site, are the series lines without borders.

Comment: Thanks it was indeed interaction between `path` definition and my script (see my comment above) !